# Algorithm of LAPACK's banded solver

Tags: matrices, matlab

I was trying to convert a MATLAB program to C program and i came across a problem where i got stuck. My Matlab program has an equation of the form 'A \ B', where '\' is mldivide in MATLAB. Matrix 'A' = D' * D, where D = nX9 matrix. Hence the matrix 'A' will be a symmetric matrix. Upon solving this and checking the `sparse` of 'A\B', the MATLAB is displaying,

```
sp\: bandwidth = 8+1+8.
sp\: is A diagonal? no.
sp\: is band density (1) > bandden (0.5) to try banded solver? yes.
sp\: is LAPACK's banded solver successful? yes.
```

I wanted to write a C code for banded solver. I checked the LAPACK library but i could not understand on how to use the same. If i `make  all`, then there will be a static library generated, but i do not want to use all the library files, since this code would go on a micro-controller and i do not want unwanted files/libraries. If there is any reference for Banded solver algorithm, so that i can replicate in 'C' program, it would be very helpful.

Matrix 'A' can be any one of the following,

```
    1.2013    0.2676    0.4950    0.1863    0.0877    0.0738    0.0001   -0.0000   -0.0001
    0.2676    1.0004    0.4776    0.1181    0.0710   -0.0243    0.0000    0.0001   -0.0001
    0.4950    0.4776    1.5497    0.1826    0.0065    0.1060   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0002
    0.1863    0.1181    0.1826    1.0705    0.1477    0.1420   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000
    0.0877    0.0710    0.0065    0.1477    1.9799    0.3652   -0.0001   -0.0000   -0.0000
    0.0738   -0.0243    0.1060    0.1420    0.3652    1.9103   -0.0000   -0.0001    0.0000
    0.0001    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0001   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0001    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0001    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
   -0.0001   -0.0001   -0.0002   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
```

or

```
    1.0891    0.2368    0.4743    0.1291   -0.2816   -0.0688    0.0002    0.0000   -0.0001
    0.2368    0.5177    0.3292    0.0683   -0.0396   -0.0652    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0001
    0.4743    0.3292    1.7228    0.0809   -0.2229    0.0101    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0003
    0.1291    0.0683    0.0809    0.9471   -0.1376   -0.0792    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.2816   -0.0396   -0.2229   -0.1376    1.8972    0.1617   -0.0001   -0.0000    0.0000
   -0.0688   -0.0652    0.0101   -0.0792    0.1617    1.3168   -0.0000   -0.0001   -0.0000
    0.0002    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0001   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0001    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0001   -0.0001   -0.0003   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to have a look at the book Matrix Computations by Golub and Van Loan. It will certainly have an algorithm for solving linear systems involving symmetric band matrices.

Comment: Thank you. Still trying to understand the concepts given in text book.

Comment: Can you say any more about $D$. How big is $n$ typically? Does $D$ always have full rank? Does it have any special structure you can exploit?

Comment: If $D$ has full rank so that $A$ is symmetric positive definite, then I would factorize $A$ by the Cholesky factorization and compute the solution from that. If $A$ is only ever $9\times 9$, I am not sure you need to worry about exploiting any savings that band structure may afford.

Comment: @K.Miller _D_ would have large number of rows, typically around 3000 to 4000. The rank of _D_ is 9. _D_ is formed by the formula, **_D = [ x .* x, y .* y, z .* z, 2 * x .* y, 2 * x .* z, 2 * y .* z, 2 * x, 2 * y, 2 * z ];_** where _x_, _y_, and _z_ are column matrix of size nX1. n might be typically 3000 to 4000. I will try with Cholesky factorization. Thank you !

Comment: You may find the article: http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/1199/01/covered/MIMS_ep2008_116.pdf and the references within helpful.

Comment: This article: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn161.pdf has a good description of the Cholesky factorization algorithm.

Comment: Thank you @K.Miller. I will check both the files. On matlab, i checked if **test = (D' * D)** is a positive definite through _chol_ and _eig_, _chol_ returned '0', _(all(eig(test) > eps))_ returned 1, and _(p == 0 && rank(test) == size(test, 1))_ returned 1, _p_ was found through _chol_ Hence found out to be a positive definite. So thats good news to use Cholesky.

Comment: Not sure it's a good idea to compute first $D^TD$ to then solve a system $D^TDX=B$. You seem to be computing the normal equations for linear least squares, but often the system is badly conditioned, and one would go for QR (or SVD) of $D$ instead of Cholesky decomposition of $D^TD$. QR should not be much slower, see for instance [this](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/103/lectures/qr.pdf).

Comment: I agree, if $D^TD$ is ill-conditioned then you may want to consider the QR factorization with column pivoting: $DP=QR$ and solve $R^TR(P^Tx)=P^Tb$. The computational costs are indeed very similar.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I finally completed a code for QR and its working just fine.